# Chalk would not log colored

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, chalk

Chalk does not log colored in Firebase logs, which I get by `firebase functions:log`, it should have some colors applied because of chalk; but it is not being applied.

I'm 100% sure chalk is installed.

Example:

```
import chalk from "chalk";
const success = chalk.greenBright;
success("Kabul lobisi oluşturuluyor..");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [Chalk documentation](https://github.com/chalk/chalk), you should be using:

```
console.log(success("Kabul lobisi oluşturuluyor.."));
```

The calls are still wrapped in `console.log(...)`.

Comment: Ah, I actually forgot that even though I made it through the documentation :D